# Scipy Spatial Distance Sub-module rejects Numpy Array

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a dataframe named, "df", with 4 columns. Three columns are independent variables: x1, x2, and x3. And, the other variable, y, is the dependent variable

I would like to calculate the distance, "pdist" between the dependent variable and each of the dependent variables, so I first converted each column to a numpy array as follows:

```
y = df[["y"]].values
x1 = df[["x1"]].values
x2 = df[["x2"]].values
x3 = df[["x3"]].values
```

When I feed these arrays through this coding pipeline I got from Github:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def distance_correlation(Xval, Yval, pval=True, nruns=500):    

    X, Y = np.atleast_1d(Xval),np.atleast_1d(Yval)     
    if np.prod(X.shape) == len(X):X = X[:, None]     
    if np.prod(Y.shape) == len(Y):Y = Y[:, None]     
    X, Y = np.atleast_2d(X),np.atleast_2d(Y)    
    n = X.shape[0]     
    if Y.shape[0] != X.shape[0]:raise ValueError('Number of samples must match')     
    a, b = squareform(pdist(X)),squareform(pdist(Y))    
    A = a - a.mean(axis=0)[None, :] - a.mean(axis=1)[:, None] + a.mean()    
    B = b - b.mean(axis=0)[None, :] - b.mean(axis=1)[:, None] + b.mean()     
    dcov2_xy = (A * B).sum() / float(n * n)     
    dcov2_xx = (A * A).sum() / float(n * n)     
    dcov2_yy = (B * B).sum() / float(n * n)     
    dcor = np.sqrt(dcov2_xy) / np.sqrt(np.sqrt(dcov2_xx) * np.sqrt(dcov2_yy))     
    if pval:         
        greater = 0         
        for i in range(nruns):             
            Y_r = copy.copy(Yval)             
            np.random.shuffle(Y_r)          
            if distcorr(Xval, Y_r, pval=False) > dcor:                 
                greater += 1         
        return (dcor, greater / float(nruns))     
    else:         
        return dcor

distance_correlation(x1, y, pval=True, nruns=500)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c720c9df4e97> in <module>
----> 1 distance_correlation(bop_sp500, price, pval=True, nruns=500)

<ipython-input-17-e0b3aea12c32> in distance_correlation(Xval, Yval, pval, nruns)
      9     n = X.shape[0]
     10     if Y.shape[0] != X.shape[0]:raise ValueError('Number of samples must match')
---> 11     a, b = squareform(pdist(X)),squareform(pdist(Y))
     12     A = a - a.mean(axis=0)[None, :] - a.mean(axis=1)[:, None] + a.mean()
     13     B = b - b.mean(axis=0)[None, :] - b.mean(axis=1)[:, None] + b.mean()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py in pdist(X, metric, *args, **kwargs)
   1997     s = X.shape
   1998     if len(s) != 2:
-> 1999         raise ValueError('A 2-dimensional array must be passed.')
   2000 
   2001     m, n = s

ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed..
```

Could anyone identify where I am going wrong? I know the error originates from the manner in which I created my numpy arrays. But, I have no clues on fixing it.

Please explain it with examples that use my variable definitions. I am new to Python

Comment: Have you checked that the value that is triggering the error is, in fact, a 2-d numpy array?  Try `print(type(x1)); print(x1.dtype, x1.shape)`.

Comment: When you report a Python error, it is a good idea to include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there, including the line that actually triggered the error.

Comment: Output: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
int32 (927, 1)

Comment: It appears like a 2d array. Which is why I am confused

Comment: @ Warren Weckesser: Thanks for the pointer. Added the traceback to the main query.

Comment: The line that generates the error calls `pdist(Y)`.  It looks like `Y` is a 1-d array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally managed to figure out the cause of the problem I faced:

The Numpy array that was being fed into the helper function was a 2d array.

While the helper function required a "Numpy vector"; i.e. a 1d Numpy array.

The best way to create it is to use the ***numpy.ravel()*** function. Hence, for my datasets, the code would be as follows (I have broken down the steps for simplicity):

```
# Create Arrays
y = df[["y"]].values
x1 = df[["x1"]].values
x2 = df[["x2"]].values
x3 = df[["x3"]].values

# Ravel Them
y = y.ravel()
x1 = x1.ravel()
x2 = x2.ravel()
x3 = x3.ravel()
```